# Where can I find more cows?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing version 0.7.1 of the Minecraft Pocket Edition and I can't find any cows!

By any chance do you know where or how I can get more? I think I killed them all but I don't know if they spawn or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All animals do spawn naturally. If you are having trouble getting them to spawn, I suggest trying this:

> As the world is not infinite (not unlimited world area) , an
> interesting new game mechanic called "animal spawn control" can be
> used. This includes removing or covering all dirt blocks on the
> surface of the world (and therefore the grass blocks) except in a
> small area to control where animals spawn. It will also increase their
> spawn rate.

Credits to the Minecraft Wiki - Pocket Edition: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition